# Access dynamic value in PHP / MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on getting a value from a database table, then getting another value based on the first value. This first part is working fine. I'm just getting a list of organization names and outputting them to a list:

```
$org_name = mysql_query('SELECT org_name FROM Orgs_Teams GROUP BY org_name');
echo "<ul>";
while ($org_row = mysql_fetch_row($org_name)) {
echo "<li>{$org_row[0]}</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

But here's where I'm stuck. I now need to get the names of each team within each organization. I'm working with a simple database table with two columns: org_name & team_name.

Ultimately I'm looking to have a nested list for my nav menu like this (which gets repeated for each Org Name):

- Org Name 1

  - Team Name 1
  - Team Name 2
  - Team Name 3

I've been messing with different queries like this:
    $team_name_query = mysql_query('SELECT team_name FROM Orgs_Teams WHERE org_name = "$org_name" ');

But haven't been able to get anything to work. My thought was that the team name query would go inside the 'while' loop and create the nested list but I'm stuck. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a column in your teams table that has the org id that team belongs to and join the tables. This gives you all the data at once

```
org_id   org_name
-------+---------
   1   |   Org 1
   2   |   Org 2


team_id    team_name    org_id
---------+------------+--------
    1    |   Team 1   |   1
    2    |   Team 2   |   1
    3    |   Team 3   |   2
    4    |   Team 4   |   2

$teams="SELECT * FROM Orgs
INNER JOIN Orgs_Teams USING (org_id)
WHERE org_id=1";
```

returns

```
org_id   org_name    team_id    team_name    org_id
-------+-----------+---------+------------+--------
    1  |   Org 1   |    1    |   Team 1   |   1
    1  |   Org 1   |    2    |   Team 2   |   1
```

Then iterate through the results to create the child list elements and use the org info from the first (or any) result to create the parent.

```
echo '<ul><li>';
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($teams)) {
    if ($i==0) echo $row['org_name'] .' <ul> ';
    echo '<li>' . $row['team_name'] .'</li>';
}
echo '</li></ul></li></ul>';
```

You can use the same query without the WHERE clause to get all your orgs and the teams within them and while iterating compare the current org_id with the previous to see whether or not you should end   the org list item you're populating with teams and start another .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop, so performing a second query while in the loop of the first loop. The other would be to push the results of your first query into an array. You can then loop the array and perform a series of queries.

```
$org_names = new array();
while ($org_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($org_name)) {
   $org_names = $org_row[];
}

echo "<ul>";
foreach($org_names as $name){
 // Do more queries
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Also as was just mentioned, performing a `JOIN` query could pull all the data needed in one recordset. Something like:

```
SELECT A.org_name, B.team_name FROM Orgs_Teams AS A JOIN Orgs_Teams AS B ON A.org_id = B.org_id WHERE A.org_name = '$org_name';
```